# Prove that $\left\{ (x;y;z)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{+*} \times\mathbb{R}:x^2+z^2=1/y\right\}$ is a submanifold and justify his dimension

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, geometric-topology

In introduction I would like to say that I just begin to study (alone) what is are submanifold so I need your help in order to be sure that my understanding of those concept is correct.

#### Question:

Let $S = \left \{ (x;y;z) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{+*} \times \mathbb{R} : x^2 + z^2 = 1/y \right \}$ . Prove that $S$ is a submanifold and justify his dimension.

#### Answer:

1- First of all let chose $\forall a \in S$ the neigboorhood $U_a$  to be equal to $ \mathbb{R}^3 - (0;0;0)$

2- Now let define $f(x;y;z) = x^2 + z^2 - 1/y $. We can remark two things. First that $ f \in C^1(U_a; \mathbb{R})$ as the sum of function $C^1(U_a)$, and segondly that $ U_a \cap S = \left \{ f = 0 \right \} $

3- Now as $f \in C^1(U_a; \mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow D \left \{ f(x;y;z)  \right \} = \vec{\bigtriangledown} \left \{ f(x;y;z) \right \} = \begin{pmatrix}
2x\\ 
\frac{1}{y^2}\\ 
2z
\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ on $U_a$. It is obvious that the $rank(\vec{\bigtriangledown} \left \{ f(x;y;z) \right \}) = 1$. As for any line we choose all the $2$ other lines can be write as a linear combinaison of the first one (trivial).

4- In conclusion we can write that by theorem/definition $rank(\vec{\bigtriangledown} \left \{ f(x;y;z) \right \}) = 3-p=1 $ and thus that $S$ is a submanifold of order $2$ of $ \mathbb{R}^3$

Is this correct?
I have mostly a doubt on my part "3- ".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The reasoning seems correct like the one of your other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868438/s-left-x-1-x-2-x-3-in-mathbbr3-x-12x-22-x-32-lambda-right/4868752#4868752). Again, you can make the proof more synthetic by invoking the inverse function theorem and showing that 0 is a regular value for the map which defines your set

Comment: @FedericoT. thank. I am solving exercices some without correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1152406/federico-t it seems that my answer is correct.

*Rem:* The gradient is of $rank=1$ as for any line we choose all the $2$ other lines can be write as a linear combinaison of the first one (trivial to prove).